# Security Error installing TFS 2010

Tags: security

Yesterday, I was having trouble trying to publish a Visual Studio web app to the wwwroot folder. I could publish it to other folders. The [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274285/visual-studio-2010-unable-to-publish-to-local-web-site-access-denied) to fix the issue was to give the logged on user full rights to the folder. That worked, but I was puzzled because the active user, BESI-CHAD/CHAD, was an Admin user (see image at the bottom of the linked page.)

Now, I am trying to uninstall and re-install TFS and I get the following error suggesting that the user Chad is not in the ServerAdmin role-but I am in that role!
[image]

What is going on here?

Error   [ Configuration Database ] TF255286: An error occurred while verifying you have the SQL server permission or role membership: serveradmin.  You may not even have enough permissions to check.  Consider adding your account to the sysadmin server role. The server hosting the databases is BESI-CHAD.  The error was: TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator..  See the log for more details.

I ended up using another SQL instance for my TFS db server, an express instance. That worked. I didnt really want another instance. Now, I want to know what happened. If there is a good theory, I might blow away Express and reinstall TFS again.

Comment: The error message said you might not have sysadmin (but looks like you do). Did you look into the installation/configuration log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis was a while back, but if memory serves, I was an Amdin on the SQL server but did not have rights to the db.